# Transactions show up on blockchain but not in multibit?

Tags: blockchain, multibit, error

1JPEobzLgKo5EKEfDVN8aJ61Pdryse6ccf This address shows transactions I was not aware of for unknown reasons, and does not show up in multibit(version 0.5.16). Which one is accurate, and how can I sync them?

Comment: I reset the blocks many times in multibit and reopened the wallet. Is there an issue with the 3 transactions for this address?(I don't see an issue)

There is more going on here since I didn't request this money. If someone wants to claim it, I need to access it before I give it back.

Comment: Reseting the blocks won't do much if it's a network or memory problem.

Comment: Could these apparent transactions be related to current bugs being exploited at this time?

Comment: Absolutely not. It's 100% a syncing issue.